# C++ implicit conversion with binary operators

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, implicit-conversion

I am writing a simple wrapper for an elementary type, and am trying to avoid having to write too many flavors of standard operators. I was hoping implicit type conversion would help, but it does not. Here's a stripped down example:

```
struct Int
{
    int _i;
    Int(int i=0) :_i{i} {}
    Int operator+ (const Int& rhs) {return _i+rhs._i;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)(Int(1) + 2); // Fine
    (void)(2 + Int(1)); // error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'Int')
}
```

I am using llvm. The first line of main compiles fine. The second causes an error. Now, what I'd hoped would happen in the second line is that 2 would be implicitly converted to Int(2), followed by a call to operator+. Why isn't that happening? Why is the implicit conversion happening in the first line?

Comment: Look at boost::operators, it helps remove the boilerplate in the cases of writing operators.

Comment: @Elliot Robinson, thanks. That has the explanation I was looking for. I hope to find it in the C++ spec at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens in the first line because the only `operator+` available is `operator+(Int&)` (which has an implicit first parameter of `Int` for the `this` instance).  The second line fails because the first parameter is an `int` and it has no clue that it needs to convert it before attempting the operation (it doesn't know it needs to use `Int::operator+`).

You can avoid that problem by making the operator a non-member friend function (http://ideone.com/YCf7wX)

```
struct Int
{
    int _i;
    Int(int i=0) :_i{i} {}
    friend Int operator+(const Int& lhs, const Int& rhs);
};

Int operator+(const Int& lhs, const Int& rhs)
{
    return lhs._i+rhs._i;
}

int main() 
{
    Int i;
    i + 5;
    5 + i;
    return 0;
}
```